# Interacting directives with individual controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive (parent) that I want to interact with another directive (children) that i've created, this children's content must be transcluded and must interact with an external controller.

Something like:

```html
<parent>
  ...
  <children ctrl="myController">
     ...(children only) to be transcluded content...
     {{like_this}} should work with myController
  </children>
  ...
</parent>
```

The parent can or can't have the children.

The parent doesn't necessarily have to be transcluded, but I need to have access of its content from the children.

Please see this fiddle:
http://jsbin.com/wohelapufa/edit?html,js,output

Edit: Also, what is causing the children content to be displayed inside of it and inside of the parent content? like the example on the fiddle.

Thanks

Comment: You need to `link` them in the directive scope so they can talk to each other

Comment: @SterlingArcher is it possible to link the directive scope to another directive scope? If so, how do I do that?